# Angular 4 - Converting JSON string response to TypeScript object

Tags: angular

I am trying to set an object from JSON string through service but the same is not working. Refer the following code:-

```
constructor(private http: Http){

}
private dataUrl='./assets/my.json';

getListNonAuthorized(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(this.dataUrl)
            .map((response:Response) => response.json())
            //.do(data => console.log(data))
            .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

The following is at client component where its being consumed:-

```
  ngOnInit() {
    //console.log('Inside');
    //alert('hi');

    this.nregMainPageService.getBorrowListNonAuthorized().subscribe(
      data => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));

      },
      error => this.errorMessage = <any>error,() => {}
    );
```

there is an object "MyList". How to set this object like this.MyList=data;
I did this also but object is not being set.

There is some small thing missing somewhere.

thanks in advance.

cheers

Comment: you call `getBorrowListNonAuthorized()` but the code sample is for `getListNonAuthorized()` so im not sure if they are the same or not. if `MyList` is a variable name in the client compoonent class, you can simply do `data => {this.MyList = data}`

Comment: call is getListNonAuthorized(). I did this.MyLaist=data and the same did not worked.

Comment: can you please clarify `not worked`? does it error? if so, what error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the format of the JSON structure. Array of object was coming which was being mapped to a custom object.